# Order Oracle Database Results as Parent And then Its Children, Then Order the Children By Date

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Consider the following table:

| employer_id | supervisor_employer_ref | date_hired |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22436 | NULL | 01/02/2006 |
| 37854 | 25558 | 07/12/2018 |
| 25558 | NULL | 10/16/2010 |
| 48796 | 25558 | 11/11/2015 |
| 28449 | 22436 | 08/14/2016 |
| 34663 | 25558 | 10/10/2019 |
| 45687 | 22436 | 04/12/2020 |

For some specific reason i have to order this table by the employer and then its supervised employers and order them by date_hired on an Oracle 12c DB.
I'm aware this is not the most ideal way of making a database but for a specific reason I have to keep it this way.

Intended result:

| employer_id | supervisor_employer_ref | date_hired |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22436 | NULL | 01/02/2006 |
| 28449 | 22436 | 08/14/2016 |
| 45687 | 22436 | 04/12/2020 |
| 25558 | NULL | 10/16/2010 |
| 48796 | 25558 | 11/11/2015 |
| 37854 | 25558 | 07/12/2018 |
| 34663 | 25558 | 10/10/2019 |
| 45687 | 22436 | 04/12/2020 |

Comment: This is a hierarchical table, so you need a recursive query. How far have you got? Where are you stuck? Please show your query and tell us which part of the task you have not been able to solve yourself.

Comment: for now i only did something like
SELECT A.*, rownum r FROM employers
ORDER BY supervisor_employer_ref, date_hired
I don't know where to go from here

Comment: This is almost nothing. Look up how to write a recursive query. Here for instance: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2. You need this for querying hierarchical data like yours. Then see how far you get and come back with a concrete problem.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - In Oracle, the most common way to query a hierarchical table is with **hierarchical** queries, using `connect by` and related features, **not** with recursive queries. Hierarchical queries may prove many times faster (because they have less work to do, and they have been significantly optimized by Oracle as they have existed since Oracle version 1).

Comment: @mathguy: I consider these recursive queries, too. Only the syntax is different. They are also explained in the link I posted.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - "Only the syntax is different"? Where do you come up with such definitive (and 100% false) pronouncements?

Comment: @mathguy: Well, it has been Oracle's way to query hierarchical data. You select rows, based on these rows you select further rows, based on those rows you select further rows. This is what the SQL standard calls a recursive query. The syntax is different, but the idea is the same. Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: The SQL standard calls the recursive WITH clause a "recursive query" - its definition has nothing to do with "hierarchical" (although that is, of course, one of the applications). Of the many substantial differences: recursive queries (recursive WITH clause) can retain state (quantities computed recursively); `connect by` can't. The most obvious application of recursive queries (vs `connect by`) is in problems where you actually need that feature. Example: compute the salary of a manager and all his subordinates (direct and indirect). Easy with recursion; can't do that with `connect by`.

Comment: Thx to everyone who helped, it solved my problem.
Used STARTS WITH supervisor_employer_ref IS NULL
            CONNECT MY PRIOR employer_id = supervisor_employer_ref
                ORDER SIBLINGS BY date_hired;

Answer (score 2):

You want a hierarchical query and to use `ORDER SIBLINGS BY`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
START WITH
       supervisor_employer_ref IS NULL
CONNECT BY
       PRIOR employer_id = supervisor_employer_ref
ORDER SIBLINGS BY date_hired;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (employer_id, supervisor_employer_ref, date_hired) AS
SELECT 22436, NULL,  TO_DATE( '01/02/2006', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 37854, 25558, TO_DATE( '07/12/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 25558, NULL,  TO_DATE( '10/16/2010', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 48796, 25558, TO_DATE( '11/11/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 28449, 22436, TO_DATE( '08/14/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 34663, 25558, TO_DATE( '10/10/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 45687, 22436, TO_DATE( '04/12/2020', 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EMPLOYER_ID | SUPERVISOR_EMPLOYER_REF | DATE_HIRED |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 22436 |  | 02-JAN-06 |
> | 28449 | 22436 | 14-AUG-16 |
> | 45687 | 22436 | 12-APR-20 |
> | 25558 |  | 16-OCT-10 |
> | 48796 | 25558 | 11-NOV-15 |
> | 37854 | 25558 | 12-JUL-18 |
> | 34663 | 25558 | 10-OCT-19 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d33d890cd2ec762c2310177011e46f94)*